# methods for identifying deliberately unmagiked filesystem

Tags: linux, file-format

I am trying to restore a system from backups around some obnoxious copy protection. It is a Linux system from an vendor that does not appear to comply with the GPL and has overwritten the header of their filesystem (the first 0xc000 bytes are cf23 repeating) so that you have to use their boot disk which checks for hardware that no longer is available and mostly does not work. I am fairly sure the block size is 4k (0x1000). the first filename in a directory entry seems to always be at 0x20 relative to the block. The filesystem does not appear to be encrypted as text is identifiable and readable. Standard methods of identification (file, blkid, mount -t auto) do not work. I know that reiserfs is used in some parts of the system as is ext2 and ext3. If anyone has any tips for things to look for to identify the filesystem type or pointers to lists of identifying characteristics of file systems it would be appreciated.

Comment: Google formats of `ext2`, `ext3` and `reiserfs` and Linux directory entries, see if they match? The inodes are pretty characteristic. The question might be more appropriate for the reverse engineering stackexchange.

Comment: Also, try `binwalk`.

Comment: If nobody here can help, you may wish to request a migration to [reverseengineering.se].

Comment: Did you run binwalk over the filesystem?

Comment: @GuntramBlohm, yes and it does appear to be a et2 file system `49152         0xC000          Linux EXT filesystem, rev 1.0, ext2 filesystem data, UUID=...` and mounts with losetup and the correct offset. Now all I need to do is fix the partition table.

Comment: @hildred: I'm curious. Why don't you attempt to find the exact extent of the file system (apparently you have found the file system) and then manually use `parted` or a similar tool to create a partition table from scratch? Creating a partition table doesn't affect the partitions, it just tells the system where to expect partitions.